# Why is the exponent operator not working? in linux shell script

Tags: shell

[image: shell programming code to find power of a number.]

I was trying to get the output of 2 to the power of 3.

but...
pow.sh: 5: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "2 ** 3" is showing.
[image: Output]

Comment: `sh` doesn't support this, try bash: `bash pow.sh`

Comment: that worked... tysm...